# Custom authentication with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, form-authentication

I want to create custom authentication with MVC3.

Scenerio:: User will have a login form, where he will input userId and password.
           These credentials are then verified against my business logic. I can not use default process, like validating it from User table then assign role etc..

My business logic will provide me a boolen value IsValidUser and UserRole.

PROBLEM:: I need to do two things:
          1. Use these values returned by Business logic in AuthoriseAttribute filter. So that I can restrict a user from accessing any particular action of a controller.(I have tried putting these values in Session variable, but not able to use them in Authorisation filter.)
          2. How to use Formsauthentication.Setauthcookie for accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom authentication you can use "ActionFilters" class for authorizing perticular controller and you can pass those parameters which you get from your "buisness logic" in the form of property,

Action Method,

```
[MyActionFilter(Property1 = "Value1", Property2 = "Value2")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

And Action Filter would be like

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: So it goes like this, I'll have to save these values in session variable and then pass these into action filters?? Is this the right way ? Since I need to find that user is authenticated in many other controllers also.

Comment: Yes you have to store UserID into session in your buisness logic. And you can retrieve it from session in ActionFilter.
Another parameter is RoleID that you can store into enum class or into database as per your requirement.

Comment: We can not access Session variable in ActionFilter :)

Comment: We can access Session Data in ActionFilters may be you are doing something wrong.
And If this solution helps you. you may mark it as an answer,

Comment: We can pass only constant values as a filter parameters. But yes this is helpfull :) thanks.

Comment: You can access your Session variables from MyActionFilter.  To do so, use the following: HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionVariableName"].  That will get you your Session variable for whatever you're looking for.